# sending json null to controller results in list with 0 elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, null, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am making a json request from the browser sending {Par: null} to my controller (C#):

```
public JsonResult MyControllerMethod(List<Guid> Par){
    //do some stuff depending on whether Par is null
}
```

but Par comes into the controller as a `List<Guid>` with 0 items, is this the correct behaviour? I thought I had passed null back before in similar situations and it remained null.

Comment: so what u can check if Par.Count() is 0, than its null otherwise not

Comment: not if it was sent back as an array object with zero elements different behaviour is required for Par = null or Par = []

Answer (score 0):

Ok, had a look at the mvc binding code

For each parameter in the url, it attempts to bind an object
if it is an IList, then it creates the list then attempts to add objects to it, hence the empty list when passing back null.

So if the parameter isn't specified then it won't bind anything, thus making it null.

The answer is therefore that if you want null on the server side, just don't specify the parameter name on the client